# End of script output before headers when using Anaconda Python in Apache

Tags: python, apache, anaconda, cgi

I am trying to run Ananaconda Python 2.7 scripts on Ubuntu using cgi but I am getting error 500 with the following error message in `var/log/apache2/error.log`.

```
 No such file or directory: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/html/app/getcapabilities.py' failed
 End of script output before headers: getcapabilities.py
```

Below is how my apache apache2.conf looks like.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/*>
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

The command `which python` gave me the path: `/home/myuser/anaconda2/bin/python`

Below is how my Python file looks like. The Python script runs fine in Windows XAMPP Apache.

```
#!/home/myuser/anaconda2/bin/python
print ("Content-Type: text/xml\n\n")
print ('\n')
print ('\n')
print ('hello')
```

I have followed [this step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365087/grant-a-user-permissions-on-www-data-owned-var-www) also but didn't work for me.

How could I fix this issue and be able to run python scripts on a web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the line ending difference in Windows and Linux. The file was in CRLF ending and it should change to LF line ending. My text editor Pycharm has a way of changing it at the bottom right corner or in the File menu as shown below. So chaning it to Unix and OS X line separator fixed the issue.

[image]

For more from Pycharm check this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html).

If you use git, this is automatically fixed when you commit the repository.

Edit:
I recently found out that making the python file executable is needed. Even if I fixed the line ending, I had a problem and making the file executable by checking the checkbox in file permissions fixed the issue.

[image]